# Options for in-memory API orchestration framework

Tags: java, workflow, in-memory, orchestration

I have a use case to implement an **in-memory orchestration framework** to complete different tasks to be performed on an API call. The API call can be visualized as a list of tasks that needs to be performed when a client calls. The tasks can be visualized as a graph.

I am currently evaluating Akka streams (graphs) to see if that solves the use-cases

**Requirements for orchestration framework**

1. Language support for Java or Scala.
2. Simplicity in defining the graph or execution flow.
3. Support for parallel tasks. The tasks can make remote REST API calls so I should be able to make parallel calls.
4. In-memory execution of the graph.
5. Good community support for the framework.

I would like to know if there are other open source frameworks available that I can use.

PS: I definitely do not want to re-invent the wheel by building my own.

Comment: found anything?